# var и оператор запятая

Tags: javascript

Почему `var i = 15,4;` генерирует ошибку? Ведь сначала должно присваивание выполнится, а затем оператор `,` вернет 4. Или как это работает? Может `,` не является оператором в данном контексте? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: куда он там вернет?

Comment: @teran куда пожелаешь.

Comment: @Topik у вас синтаксически запятая воспринимается как разделитель, после нее ожидается имя переменной. В вашем случае должно быть так `var i = (15,4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратимся к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement). Синтаксис использования `var`, следующий:

```
VariableStatement[Yield, Await]:
    var VariableDeclarationList[+In, ?Yield, ?Await];

VariableDeclarationList[In, Yield, Await]:
    VariableDeclaration[?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
    VariableDeclarationList[?In, ?Yield, ?Await] , VariableDeclaration[?In, ?Yield, ?Await]

VariableDeclaration[In, Yield, Await]:
    BindingIdentifier[?Yield, ?Await] Initializer[?In, ?Yield, ?Await] opt
    BindingPattern[?Yield, ?Await] Initializer[?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
```

Отсюда видно, что в данном случае запятой разделяются именно `BindingIdentifier`.

Число `4` не является идентификатором, поэтому и показывается синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что никакого универсального правила нету? И нужно знать синтаксис каждой инструкции, что бы не допускать таких ошибок?

Comment: @Topik, формально можно к _приоритету_ операций привязаться, у запятой наименьший приоритет. Однако в этом случае нужно будет запоминать приоритеты всех операций :-) Но в самой спецификации ничего про приоритет нет.

Comment: не понимаю причем тут приоритет. Ведь  с var ","  уже не является оператором, а является разделителем и после него ожидается идентификатор. А значит знание приоритета тут не помогут.

Comment: @Topik, вот ты и ответил на свой вопрос :-)

Comment: просто у Вас хотел узнать, что мои догадки верны.

Comment: @Topik, на самом деле таких специфичных случаев не так уж много.

Answer (score 3):

`var` объявляет переменную и факультативно присваивает ей значение. Декларация это инструкция (statement), а не выражение (expression), и по синтаксису после запятой в объявлении возможны только другие объявления переменных (факультативно с присваиванием). Вот так работает:

```js
var i;
i = 15,4; // Присваивает 15, возвращает 4.
console.log(i);
```

Теперь сначала происходит присваивание, потом возврат второго операнда.

Comment: "второго операнда"? Не думаю.

Comment: @Igor А как вы в этом контексте назовёте четвёрку? Вот, например, [определение из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F): «Оператор запятая выполняет каждый из его операндов (слева направо) и возвращает значение последнего операнда».

Comment: Посмотрите на значение переменной `i`.

Comment: Так я ведь не спорю, что `i` присваивается `15`. Я имею в виду, что строка `i = 15,4;` возвращает `4`. Проверьте в консоли браузера или Node.js. Это две независимые вещи: присваивание `15` переменной `i` и возврат значения, вычисленного оператором запятой (в данном случае это `4`).

Comment: Хорошо было бы добавить в ответ, что строка `i = 15,4` возвращает `4`, что бы это было видно в консоли браузера.

Comment: Добавил в комментарии к строке.