# Почему ошибка в тесте?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Подскажите пожалуйста почему ошибка в тесте ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [var и оператор запятая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947763/var-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что там не 1.5, а 1,5. Это вопрос с подвохом на внимательность. Сначала а = 1, потом 5 -1, а уже потом 4*2 = 8.

Answer (score 0):

Надо различать запятую и точку в синтаксисе:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F

```js
let a = (1.5 - 1) * 2;
let b = (1, 5 - 1) * 2;
console.log("a=", a);
console.log("b=", b)
```